# How to make parent window size fit children zk?

Tags: flexbox, messagebox, zk

Is there any way that a window takes only as much space as its children need?

```
<window id="ecDialog" title="${resolver.nls.mes_hdEmptyCompleteDialogTitle}"
    closable="true" sizable="true" mode="modal" border="normal"
    apply="com.camline.skmes.mes.webgui.controller.dialog.EmptyCompleteDialogController">

    <borderlayout>
        <center style="padding: 5px 5px;">
            <vbox vflex="min" align="center" pack="center">
                <label id="confirmText" style="font-size:150%;"/>
            </vbox>
        </center>

    </borderlayout>
</window>
```

Right now, I only see the title bar and it allocates no space for the actual content (borderlayout). I want the window to be just as big as to fit the text, however long the text may be. I tried setting vflex="min" and hflex="min" but it doesn't change anything.

**Basically the same functionality as Messagebox**

Answer (score 0):

You made the mistake b setting the `vflex="min"` to the wrong component.
Please try this :

```
<window id="ecDialog" title="testWindow" closable="true" sizable="true" mode="modal" border="normal" vflex="min">
    <borderlayout>
        <center style="padding: 5px 5px;" vflex="min" hflex="1">
            <vbox align="center" pack="center">
                <label id="confirmText" style="font-size:150%;" value="test case" hflex="1"/>
            </vbox>
        </center>
    </borderlayout>
</window>
```

[Link to fiddle where you can see the result of this zul.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2iue1lg/8-Custom-modal-window)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to make it work by putting the label in a div : <div width="350px" align="center">
   <label id="confirmText" style="font-size:150%;" multiline="true" />
  </div>

Comment: If you don't need the vbox, always try to avoid it. Choose instead div or vlayout. This is much lichter in html